# Spring CachingConnectionFactory not reaping when idle

Tags: jms, connection-pooling, spring-integration, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I am using spring `CachingConnectionFactory` as in the below configuration to cache MQ sessions. I can see that the caching is working as expected:

- it opens a single MQ connection
- creates new sessions as needed and reuses them

My application has short lived peaks in message traffic. So when there is a peak, the session size bloats and remains there long after the peak. I am looking for a way of reaping these idle sessions after a specific period of inactivity. Is there anyway to achieve this?

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="mqQueueConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jms/MyJMSQueueConnectionFactory" />

<bean id="userConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="mqQueueConnectionFactory"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="queueConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="userConnectionFactory"></property>
    <property name="reconnectOnException" value="${ssa.mq.cachesession}"></property>
    <property name="cacheProducers" value="${ssa.mq.cacheproducer}"></property>
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="${ssa.mq.producer.sessionsize}"></property>
    <property name="cacheConsumers" value="${ssa.mq.cacheconsumers}"></property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the `sessionCacheSize`; any sessions that are closed when the cache size is exceeded will be physically closed the next time they are used.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? - "any sessions that are closed when the cache size is exceeded will be physically closed the next time they are used". Are you saying session size will grow to any number on peak load and then drop back to the sessionCacheSize when the load is lower?

Comment: Correct - see [session creation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jms/src/main/java/org/springframework/jms/connection/CachingConnectionFactory.java#L227) and [session closing (logical Vs. physical)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jms/src/main/java/org/springframework/jms/connection/CachingConnectionFactory.java#L307). `TRACE` level logging will give you the full picture.